# Can I make the primary constructor private while keeping auxiliary constructors public in Scala?

Tags: scala, constructor

As I intend only overloaded constructors for public use to create the class instances I'd like to make the primary constructor private. Is this possible in Scala?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
class A private (x: Int) {
  def this() = this(42)
}
```

Comment: You can also call the private primary constructor from the companion object; useful for factory methods.

Answer (score 5):

Yes - you can determine the visibility of the primary constructor by specifying the modifiers after the class name, e.g.:

```
class Foo private (a: Int, b: String) {
   // ...
}
```

And then of course the auxiliary constructors can still (in fact, must) reference this primary constructor, while still being declared as public.